# LIKE vs связь многие ко многим

Tags: php, mysql

Есть люди которые тестировали относительно MySQL данные запросы?

Пример: Есть новость с множеством тегов (теги повторяются, по факту их 50-100 на 300к новостей), что профитнее юзать LIKE по ячейке с тегами, или создавать связь многие ко многим (используя 3 таблицы).

P.S. фишка в том что если юзать связь многие ко многим, связующая табличка выйдет на 1кк-1,5кк записей. (вот и стал думать)

P.S.2 Если многие ко многим, пример запроса не помешал-бы. (Наглядного и эффективного хватило бы)

Comment: Многие ко многим. Вам не помешало бы ознакомиться с принципами работы индексов, вопросы бы сами отпали.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю @Etki. Если Вы почитаете про хранение индексов, Вы поймете, когда их использовать, а когда нет (и как правильно). Из своего опыта скажу, как-то в одной очень известной CMS нашел запрос, который из-за `LIKE` очень нагружал базу (высокая нагрузка у проекта).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск через таблицу, всё же будет быстрее. Тем более это [нормализация](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/283878) базы данных.

```
SELECT * FROM news
JOIN news_tags ON news.id = news_tags.news_id
JOIN tags ON news_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.name = 'название тега 1' OR tags.name = 'название тега 2'
```

[Статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/70640/) про индексы.
И англоязычный [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258696/mysql-join-vs-like-faster-selects)

Я писал это в комментариях, но озвучу и здесь. Как-то в одной очень известной CMS нашел запрос, который из-за LIKE очень нагружал базу (высокая нагрузка у проекта).

Answer (score 1):

Если теги часто повторяются в одних и тех же комбинациях (ваш вопрос, например, с тегами php-mysql и вопросов именно с таким набором тегов очень много). Можно использовать следующий подход:

```
-- Список возможных тегов
create table Tags(
  tagID int not null auto_increment,
  name  varchar(128) not null,
  primary key(tagID)
);
-- Наборы тегов
create table TagSets(
  tsetID int not null auto_increment,
  allIDs varchar not null,
  primary key(tsetID)
);
-- Теги в наборе
create table TagsInSet(
  tsetID int not null,
  tagID  int not null,
  primary key(tagID, tsetID),
  foreign key (tsetID) references TagSets(tsetID),
  foreign key (tagID) references Tags(tagID)
);
```

Идея в том, что каждому возможному набору тегов выделяется своя ID-набора (`tsetID`) и в записи новости мы добавляем не поле типа *varchar* со списком названий тегов, а поле *int* содержащее ID-набора для данной статьи. В принципе таких наборов могут быть миллионы, по количеству возможных комбинаций всех тегов. Но по факту количество наборов достаточно сильно ограничено их природой. Т.е. таких наборов будет заметно меньше (возможно на порядки), чем статей, их использующих.

Самый сложный код получается при создании или редактировании статьи. Человек (или алгоритм) вводит нужные теги, мы собираем ID всех этих тегов и ищем подходящий набор. Если набор существует то в статью просто заносим его ID, если нет - то создаем новый, делая запись в таблице Tags. В поле `allIDs` кладем отсортированный список ID-тегов (в принципе это некоторое нарушение НФ, но позволит быстро найти готовый набор, когда будем создавать следующую статью с таким же набором). При этом в TagsInSet кладем отдельные записи с ID созданного набора и ID каждого из тегов в наборе (как и положено в реляционных базах для списков).

Если порядок следования тегов в конкретной статье важен - придется добавить порядковый номер тега в TagsInSet и в allIDs хранить список отсортированный в нужном порядке. И это раздует таблицу и может свести на нет выигрыш от данной схемы в целом.

Поиск статей (News) с любым из тегов (mysql, php) выглядит примерно так:

```
select * from News
 where tsetID in(
    select S.tsetID
      from TagsInSet S, Tags T
     where S.tagID=T.tagID and T.name in('mysql','php')
 );
```

Поиск статей с обоими тегами одновременно (mysql И php):

```
select * from News
 where tsetID in(
    select S.tsetID
      from TagsInSet S, Tags T
     where S.tagID=T.tagID and T.name in('mysql','php')
     group by S.tsetID
     having count(1)=2 --// 2 - кол-во тегов в условии
 );
```

Что касается LIKE, то строки вроде 'ABC%' по индексу он может найти быстро, но т.к. вы собираетесь искать теги то строка будет вида '%ABC%' - в таком случае использование индекса в принципе невозможно и запрос должен будет перебрать все ваши 300к записей для поиска нужных.